# Unable to access website externally from windows server 2012 r2

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2012-r2

Added `DNS` entries for site.
When I'm hitting for `www.site.example.com` in browser then I'm getting windows server IIS screen.
But when I'm hitting for `www.site.example.com:83` then no screen displayed and browser showing an error as `This site can’t be reached`.

When on the server I'm hitting `localhost:83` then it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that your firewall allows connections on port 83. Plus if your using Azure, Amazon EC2 or similar, you have to allow port 83 there too

Comment: I have check using `netstat -a -n` it displays me 83 port with state `listening`. How could I check whether firewall allows connections on port 83 or not?